# Adding custom data to Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using Chart.js to create some grahs within a custom PHP/HTML site

I have a graph which works great, however i'd like to add some supplementary information to the tooltips. Ideally i'd like to add a few lines with dates on below the data for each dataset. so between the 2 datasets in this example

[image]

The information should be as follows

```
Garforth Medical Centre: 108
Visited
15/04/2019
17/04/2019
Dr. Laybourn & Partners: 24
```

Here is the bulk of my JS for this graph for reference...

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

```js
callbacks: {
     // Use the footer callback to display the sum of the items showing in the tooltip
     afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var visits = '13/03/19';
      return 'Visits : ' + visits;
     },
    },
```

I've gone down the route of using callbacks as per a suggestion (thanks @WhiteHat) however I need the data to be unique for each label.

In my head I'd do a foreach value of the label, do

```js
var visits = '13/03/19';
return 'Visits : ' + visits;
```

but i'm struggling to fight my way through the documentation at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html?h=examples to see how i'd go about doing this.

Thanks

Henry

Comment: you can use [tooltip callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) to add info...

Comment: thanks @WhiteHat I have updated my code, but struggling with the loop. I wonder if you'd be able to point me in the right direction. Please

Comment: I don't really follow, I kinda get the end result, but I don't see where the extra info exists in the data, or where you're going to pull it from...

Comment: i'll actually be pulled longer term via PHP where the value in the database = the label. however for now we could start with just a static value of 31/01/19 for example.